# DRF: Filter several fields in one request

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have to implement set of filters (see picture). My code works fine for 1 filter e.g.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/constructions?field=developer&value=1 -- filter by developer with id =1

I want to filter by several filters in one request.
I can use something like this

1. http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/constructions?field=field1_field2&value=value1_value2
2. Split field1_field2 --> [field1, field2] and so on (it's not perfect)

Is there better way to solve my issue?

[image]

**views.py**

```
class ConstructionView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ConstructionSerializer
    queryset = Construction.objects.all()
    pagination_class = BasePagination

    def list(self, request):
        field = request.GET.get('field', None)
        value = request.GET.get('value', None)
        if field is not None and value is not None:
            queryset = Construction.objects.filter(**{field:value})
        else:
            queryset = Construction.objects.all()
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = ConstructionSerializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        else:
            serializer = ConstructionSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: Why don't you use the field name as the query parameter name? For example, `/api/constructions?developer=1&name=Foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list at your `query_params` you can use that approach. You can check if your value of your `query_params` is a list or string and apply it to a filter. `<fieldname>__in` works for list.

```
custom_filter = {'field__in': request.query_params.get('field'), 'value__in': request.query_params.get('value')}
queryset = Construction.objects.filter(**custom_filter )
```

Maybe [djangorestframework-queryfields](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-queryfields/) helps your for a bunch of common work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get multiple object by their ID, you can try something like this:

`Construction.objects.filter(id__in = [1,2])`

It will return objects with 1,2 IDs